# Python: Problem with custom mapping in ElasticSearch

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, mapping

I am trying to index a couple of JSON files (example file [here](https://gist.github.com/anjani-dhrangadhariya/5fd8ef8c102ce8932a161466aa905a1b#file-example-json)) using [ElasticSearch Client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.10.1/) in Python. The files follow a specific mapping. Please find the mapping JSON file [here](https://gist.github.com/anjani-dhrangadhariya/5fd8ef8c102ce8932a161466aa905a1b#file-mapping-json).

Using ElasticSearch client in Python, I create an index with this mapping.

```
def getMappings():
    with open('/home/mapping.json') as f:
        d = json.load(f)
        return d

mapping = { "mapping": { "properties": getMappings() } }    
es = Elasticsearch( [{u'host': u'127.0.0.1', u'port': b'9200'}] )
es.indices.create(index='my-index', ignore=400, body=mapping) # mapping is a dictionary

counter = 0
directory = 'home/directory/'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    fullFileName = directory + filename
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(fullFileName,'r') as open_file:
            d = json.load(open_file)
            counter = counter + 1
            es.index(index='my-index', id=counter, body=d)
            #print(fullFileName)
```

The code executes without any problem and documents get indexed. However, the index seems to have been created without the mapping structure.

Upon checking the Fields in the created index, only one field is returned.

```
indices_names = []
for elem in es.cat.indices(index='my-index', format="json"):
    indices_names.append( elem['index'] )

dict_index_fields = {}

for index in indices_names: 
    mapping = es.indices.get_mapping(index)
    dict_index_fields[index] = []
    for field in mapping[index]['mappings']['properties']:
        dict_index_fields[index].append(field) 

print(dict_index_fields)
```

The `print(dict_index_fields)` results into `{'my-index': ['FullStudiesResponse']}` which is not a `Field` in the mapping file, but is a part of the JSON documents to be indexed. Am I doing something completely wrong here? I suspect the issue with the nested structure in the documents to be indexed. Any hint or help is appreciated.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g14v9vwC7XEKJYyVUh92vmLLxCWgwXIT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Don't use google drive when sharing links here. Use secret https://gist.github.com/ or similar but not google drive files that require permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the nudge @JoeSorocin I just changed the files to public gists and updated the links.

Comment: The mapping you're provided is massively off -- there are too many errors. I've generated a correct one for you [here](https://gist.github.com/jzzfs/58e7a85b3b95249eb079c095aeb6edd4). Hope it helps.

Comment: @JoeSorocin Thank you so much for correcting the mapping dict. The problem remains the same. Indexing does not pick up on the provided mapping except the root node keys. I assume it needs to be a flat JSON document.

Comment: Did you apply this correct mapping -- meaning did you pass is inside of `es.indices.create`? The docs surely don't need to be flat...